# iOS application crash without any error message

Tags: ios, crash

So, this is a bit baffling, and I don't know what to do. My application crashes randomly after a few minutes of use, always on the same action (the same modal view being dismissed). The crash doesn't always occur, but it happens on the simulator and on a real device.

I've tried to :

- Make sure I'm in **debug mode** (of course, but nothing happened)
- Enable **guard malloc** (nothing)
- Run inside the **Instruments** (nothing)
- Run the iPhone Simulator directly from a terminal, and then attach LLDB to the application (nothing more then a classic *exit* with code 0)
- Add an **exception breakpoint** (nothing meaningful)

The last thing I tried was adding a breakpoint on the `exit` function. The application stops, but I don't have a meaningful stack trace either (see below).

[image: Stack trace on exit]

Also, I'm doing some pretty barebones stuff with Lua, so it might be related. The Mac OSX logs show this weird line here :

```
5/15/12 2:16:57.190 PM com.apple.debugserver-170.1: 1 +0.000000 sec [233b/1a03]: error: ::read ( 1, 0x10af80a60, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
```

If you have any idea on how to get a more meaningful stack trace, for instance at least get the library/module/file/whatever responsible for the `exit` call, it would help greatly!

Comment: The error log entry seems to indicate there is a problem with the com.apple.debugserver call dealing with a file.  Does your phone crash on an actuall iOS device running 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Breakpoint navigator (shortcut: cmd + 6) and at the bottom left you'll see a little + icon. Click on it and select "Add exception breakpoint". Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried that as well. It doesn't get any more meaningful... (Question edited)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but do you have -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib in your other linker flags for your target? This causes odd crashes in various places at least on the simulator - the cordova/phonegap generated apps include this flag, and some versions of flurry and urbanairship use it too.

If you replace -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib with -weak-lSystem /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib and the crashes go away.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using these libraries, and the "Other Linker Flags" field is empty...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider it painful, but maybe you could try putting NSLog statements in all your methods?

btw, try delaying your modal dismissal by a second or two, to eliminate that being an indicator of the problem.

what else is your app doing?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about delaying the modal dismissal. I will try it. As for putting NSLog statements in all my methods, honestly, I would only consider that as a last resort, it is a pretty big project.